# MySQL inner join same table based on field value

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a table structure as follows:

```
|id|record_id|key    |vale
|1 |2        |email  |xx@xxx.com    
|2 |2        |name   |John    
|3 |2        |tel    |676776    
|4 |3        |email  |tt@rrt.com    
|5 |3        |name   |James    
|6 |3        |tel    |7676767     
|7 |4        |emal   |5656@rtrt.com
```

I'm trying to display the "email" and "name" that match the `record_id` from the same table.

My attempted cfquery is as follows, but sadly I'm not getting any success.

```
<cfquery name="getStatic" datasource="#session.odbcname#">
    SELECT  *
    FROM    field_values n
    INNER JOIN field_values e
    ON e.key
    AND e.field_values.key = 'name'
    WHERE n.field_values.record_id = e.field_values.record_id
</cfquery>
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify a few things: 1) When referencing the columns, use *either* a table alias OR a full table name - not both (which causes a syntax error). 2) The `INNER JOIN` must join `ON` whatever columns the referenced tables have in common, ie `record_id` 3) It may not cause a syntax error, but for readability and performance, it is best to specify only the columns needed, instead of using `select *`.

Comment: show please expected result set

Comment: Hi, Im trying to output the email and name vales together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.value email, t2.value name
from field_values t1
inner join field_values t2
on t1.record_id = t2.record_id
and t1.key = 'email'
and t2.key = 'name';
```

Comment: Hi, sadly I get thet error `Unknown column 't1.vale' in 'field list'`

Comment: what is the name of fourth column in your table? is it `value`?

Comment: Right. Fixed my answer

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error... `Element VALUE is undefined in T1.` I have tried to output `#t1.value#` and `#value#`

Comment: @elixireu the columns are aliased in the query.  They are now named: "email" and "name".  Use #email# or #name# to see the values in cfoutput